# Android In-app purchases with Phonegap

Tags: android, paypal, cordova, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there any way to implement Android In-app purchases with Phonegap? I can't find any information abt this issue. For example I can do IAP on iOS using InAppPurchaseManager Phonegap plugin. But there are no relevant plugins for Android.

And if it's impossible for some reason can you suggest any other way to implement instant(or renewable) payments for Phonegap Android app. I know there is a PayPal API for Android but I can't use it because of Phonegap...

The only way I can see is to use PayPal API for web-sites (and I have website where I can implement it) but I believe it's a bad user experience.

Please Help! Any suggestions!? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partner and I just open sourced Android PayPal PhoneGap plugin and did a pull request to incorporate it into [the PhoneGap plugin repository](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android). 
The plugin and instructions are now available on a branch here in this [fork](https://github.com/paulb777/phonegap-plugins/tree/addAndroidPayPalPlugin/Android/PayPalPlugin).

Let us know if you have any feedback.

Comment: It's now in the main PhoneGap Plugin repo at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/PayPalPlugin

Comment: Good news indeed! Now I have some other priorities to do, but I'll definitely try this plugin later.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal recently released a [PhoneGap plugin for Android](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK-PhoneGap), which is actively supported by PayPal.

Comment: I would believe that any such app would be in direct violation with Goole's policy?

Comment: No, the [Google](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) / [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies) policy of their app stores is that digital goods within apps must go through their app store, but physical goods and services can be processed by third parties.  PayPal has many such integrations.  There's a lot of misinformation floating around StackOverflow about this topic...

Comment: The OP did not say anything about what he will be selling, but you are absolutely right about physical goods, or movie tickets etc.